# layout_width is missed after using <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout> tag

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, xml-namespaces

I'm new to Android development and trying to learn it by the book **Android for Absolute Beginners**

One of the chapters is about android U.I Design and i'm learning about different android layouts in this chapter .

My problem starts after adding `<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout >` Tag to my code in order to use android SlidindPaneLayout .

Before Adding this Tag I could use android:layout_width or android:layout_height and ... attribute in all of objects . But now it can be only used inside my  sliding layout tag

Here is a little simplified version of my code which as you can see android:layout_width is not used inside Linear Layout because Eclipse doesn't accept it ;)
for more detail look at the link below Please ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="hamid.traingin.hellouniverse.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/spLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/milkyway1">
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Here is a picture of my problem in Eclipse IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The xml code is valid, you can and should add the layout_width and layout_height to you LinearLayout without raising a compiler error. I'm not too sure why Eclipse does not allow you to do so, but Android Studio does:

[image]

Comment: I tried to run in my android device and everything was correct . I should get rid of Eclipse very soon

Comment: That would be a wise choice :)

Comment: @HAMIDREZA, if you are restricted to use eclipse because of the book you are reading, then consider this course for Android development: https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853 . It is based on Android Studio and created by Google engineers